# Assigning ID's to fields that are echoed using PHP inside a while loop

Tags: php, html, input

I currently have two dropdown menus that a user will select the course and a golfer which will load a scorecard.

What I am trying to do now is when a user enters a value into the "Score" field I want the "points" to be automatically shown ("Points" is a read only input field). To do this I am assuming that I will have to give each table row for score and points a specific ID.

```
echo "<div class='scorecardTable'>
<table 'id=scorecardTable'>
<tr>
<th>HoleNumber</th>
<th>Par</th>
<th>Stroke Index</th>
<th>Score</th>
<th>Points</th>
</tr>'";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['holeNumber'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['par'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['strokeIndex'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> <input type='text' maxlength='2' id='score' /></td>";
    echo "<td> <input type='text' id='points' readonly></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

From the above code I am using PHP to print the information from my database but I was just wondering if anyone would know how to assign a unique ID to each of the score and points input fields so I can apply the calculation to each user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a variable to count the rows and set the id.

```
$rowIndex = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['holeNumber'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['par'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['strokeIndex'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> <input type='text' maxlength='2' id='score$rowIndex' /></td>";
    echo "<td> <input type='text' id='points$rowIndex' readonly></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $rowIndex++;
}
```

You may also use

```
id='score[$rowIndex]'
```